# Обучающая выборка для задачи класификации изображений

Tags: нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

Нужно составить обучающую выборку изображения для НС, которая должна определять содержит ли картинка запрещенную символику (ОПГ и т.д.).
Какой масштаб лучше использовать, что бы сеть умела определять символику с некоторыми отклонениями (складки на одежде, иной угол обзора и т.д.)?

Answer (score 1):

Общее правило - всегда,для любой задачи распознавания изображения лучше использовать максимально возможное разрешение (масштаб). Иногда бывает достаточно и меньшего, но лучше - всегда больше.

А дальше все будет определяться используемой архитектурой и реализацией нейронной сети и набором данных, который вы будете использовать для обучения.